# How can I create a merged object from an array of objects that preserves properties in the original object not changed from the new incoming object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, javascript-objects

I have to object/array sets...

```
var test = [{id: 1, prop: 'bill', location: 'san diego'},{id: 11, prop: 'bright'}];
var test2 = [{id: 1, prop: 'casey'},{id: 11, prop: 'candle'}];
```

Ultimately I want the objects from test2 to change properties in test but preserve the location property in the original object because it has not changed or even referenced in test2.

What I did was setup a mapping that key's the id and uses each object as the value.

The problem occurs that the value of the new object per the key will overwrite the previous original object in whole. Therefore, the location property gets wiped out from the original array.

notably from Object.assign() the bare object not presented as an array of objects will preserve integrity of the original object and only change underlying properties.

Here is an example of both:

array of objects:

```
var o1 = [{id: 1, prop: 'bill', location: 'san diego'},{id: 11, prop: 'bright'}];
var o2 = [{id: 1, prop: 'casey'},{id: 11, prop: 'candle'}];
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // 0: {id: 1, prop: "casey"} 1: {id: 11, prop: "candle"} c: 3
```

singular object:

```
var o1 = {id: 1, prop: 'bill', location: 'san diego'};
var o2 = {id: 1, prop: 'casey'};
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // {id: 1, prop: "casey", location: "san diego", c: 3}
```

processing the object in a single format has the desired affect so perhaps the answer lies in that fact.  Is there a concise way of doing this or will this need to be built out in a looped fashion processing one record at a time? If so, what would be an example of this?

Here is the mapping code I was working on:

```
var test = [{id: 1, prop: 'bill', location: 'san diego'},{id: 11, prop: 'bright'}];
var first = new Map();
for (const value of test) {
    //console.log(key + ' = ' + value.id);
    first.set(value.id, value);
    //console.log(first);
}
var test2 = [{id: 1, prop: 'casey'},{id: 11, prop: 'candle'}];
var second = new Map();
for (const value of test2) {
    second.set(value.id, value);
}

var merged = new Map([...first, ...second]);

let mergedArray = [];
for (var value of merged.values()) {
  console.log(' = ' + value);
    mergedArray.push(value);
}

console.log('merged', mergedArray);
// console.log(merged)

// console.log('second2', second);
// console.log('first2 ', first);
```

Comment: Apply KISS principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const merged = test.map(ele => {
  const found = test2.find(({id}) => id === ele.id) || {}
  return {...ele, ...found}
})
```

- loop over `test`
- find the same id element in `test2` (if not found set an empty object)
- return the merged object where `test` is the source and `test2` contains the overwrites/additions

Comment: ok so what I believe I was doing wrong... Essentially this is the same thing except each one of my map id's is a value so when it merges the entire value upon merge is getting replace... But I needed each object to replace the properties which is what you did. interesting.

Comment: If my solution was the thing you were looking for please mark it as the accepted one or ask for further help

Comment: edited it to work even if `test2` has members not existing in `test`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```js
const test = [{
    id: 1,
    prop: 'bill',
    location: 'san diego'
  }, {
    id: 11,
    prop: 'bright'
  }, {
    id: 12, //not in test2
    prop: 'something',
    location: 'NY'
  },
  {
    id: 13, //no "prop" in test2
    prop: 'something',
    location: 'NY'
  }
];
const test2 = [{
    id: 1,
    prop: 'casey'
  }, {
    id: '11',
    prop: 'candle'
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    something: false
  },
  {
    id: 100, // not in test
    prop: 'other'
  }
];
test.forEach(t => {
  const t2 = test2.find(t2 => t2.id == t.id);//=== for exact match
  if (t2)
    t.prop = t2.prop || t.prop;
});
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Using double equals `==` is a bad idea, string and number ids would be indistinguishable and merged

Comment: @Marcin This is done with purpose. In this case they should be indistinguishable.

Comment: this isn't it. the integrity of the initial object must stay the same for properties that aren't being copied over from the incoming object

Comment: I want to make it clear too why this isn't sufficient. Your solution depends on the statement to match a property your looking for. While the above matches the entire object. What is incoming must override whether it's less or more.  What is there must not be overridden if there is no matching overriding property. And the above solution is easier to read especially with the KISS principle you suggested earlier

Comment: as you can see from the snippet, `test` is updated **iff** `id` matches (loosely `==` or exact `===`) *and* the property (`prop`) exists in `test2`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev but i don't want it to worry about any property in the object other than matching up with the id. The other properties should be free to change.

Comment: this exactly what my snippet does.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this answer with the use of the Map() function such that an object can be set to a key value first. The accepted answer is short and concise but this may have additional value.

```
var test = [{id: 1, prop: 'bill', location: 'san diego'},{id: 11, prop: 'bright'}];
  var test2 = [{id: 1, prop: 'casey'},{id: 11, prop: 'candle'}];

  const map = new Map(test.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]));
  for (const item of test2) {
    if (map.has(item.id)) {
      // map.set( item.id, item ); // replace the item value
      map.set(item.id, { ...map.get(item.id),
        ...item
      }); 
    }
  }
  console.log(Array.from(map));
```